# Detect if a string consists of a substring of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have the user input a string A for example "sun is clear". I have a string B in the database "sun cloud rain". How would I detect if part of *String A* is part of *String B*?

I used `@sky.include?(activity.sky)` where `@sky` is *String A* and `activity.sky` is *String B*. This works only when String A is **sun**.

Comment: do you mean that a word of `String A` a is a one of words of `String B`?

Comment: Yes, the condition should pass if one of the words from String A matches one of the words in String B.

Comment: For any strings `A` and `B`, a part of `A` is always a part of `B`. Proof: The empty string is part of `A` and is also a part of `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the strings into two arrays

```
a = "sun is clear".split
b = "sun cloud rain".split
```

and compute the intersection

```
a & b
# => ["sun"] 
(a & b).empty?
# => false
```

If the intersection is not empty, then they share pieces. Otherwise, you can also compute the difference of `a` - `b`

```
(a - b).size == a.size
# => false
```

Comment: This is a simple as `(a & b).empty?`

Comment: +1 Sets in Ruby make this sort of array work so clean.

Comment: very clean very easy to understand. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

To match a word of String A a is a one of words of String B use the following:

```
activity.sky.split( /\s+/ ).any? {|s| @sky.include?(s) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If neither `A` nor `B` itself includes a duplicate of words, then you can check like this:

```
A = "sun is clear"
B = "sun cloud rain"
"#{A} #{B}" =~ /\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b/ # => 0 (non-nil means there is a common word)

A = "sun is clear"
B = "cloud rain"
"#{A} #{B}" =~ /\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b/ # => nil (nil means there is no common word)
```

Otherwise, you can insert some non-letter non-space character (e.g., `"|"`) between the two strings:

```
A = "sun is sun"
B = "sun cloud rain"
"#{A}|#{B}" =~ /\b(\w+)\b.*|.*\b\1\b/ # => 0

A = "sun is sun"
B = "cloud rain"
"#{A}|#{B}" =~ /\b(\w+)\b.*|.*\b\1\b/ # => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

split and then put & operator

```
(@sky.split(" ") & activity.sky.split(" ")).empty?
```